# Markdown in Doxygen with @file

Tags: markdown, doxygen, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to document some source code templates with doxygen and markdown using fenced code blocks

```
~~~cpp
/// @file    filename.h
~~~
```

But Doxygen seems to process the `@file` command even though its verbatim code which results in the warning

```
warning: the name `filename.h' supplied as the second argument
in the \file statement is not an input file
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the "@" sign. Use `\@file` instead.

Comment: Why is it necessary to escape? A fenced code block shall be treated as a verbatim code block, meaning the doxygen ignores all commands in between and used the contents unparsed.

Comment: This answer make work for the literal example, but it won't work for `\@brief my brief description` -- it will not be correctly utilized by DOxygen. I'm in the same boat here with @Aeon512