# DOxygen not playing well with GitHub-flavored markdown documents that use codeblocks and backticks when converting to HTML

Tags: html, markdown, codeblocks, doxygen

I've been trying to get DOxygen to correctly format and output my markdown files that use fenced code blocks and back ticks for inline code marks, like I use on GitHub.

Default config of DOxygen was having none of that nonsense, so I played the, *"let's see what this setting does!"* game. I've also been browsing their bug reports from the past couple of years, and haven't found any definitive fix or configuration that bypasses my problem, as none of the code examples in them worked from my end. Also, content between backticks are getting special formatting, but it's not code-style formatting that you're used to seeing on SO and GH -- e.g., it has no `background color`. A slightly different font doesn't really pop when going through a doc compared to what I've been used to.

The crux of the issue has been getting DOxygen-identifying syntax within markdown codeblocks to not completely break the file output starting on the comment in the codeblock. Instead of getting formatting like this:

---

Markdown **stuff**

```
#include <blarg>

/*!
* \brief brief description here
* \file filename.ext
*/

class ClassName{
private:
int magicnumber;
public:
void dostuff();
};
```

Some `markdown` stuff

---

I'll end up getting from DOxygen:

---

Markdown **stuff**

``` #include

/*! **

---

Or, some other similarly broken output. The closest I've come to a fix was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872881/markdown-in-doxygen-with-file), but when I tried that, the brief description wasn't actually working from DOxygen-generated files, even though the HTML page itself looked fine, minus the ugly workaround.

So, from a default config, what all do I need to set to get the functionality I'm looking for? I've got other tools that can handle my markdown to html conversions, but I want to unify documentation and leverage DOxygen's power, if possible.

I've tried DOxygen versions 1.8.7 and 1.8.11

EDIT: This is only ONE solution that I attempted. To add them all would be unrealistic and make this question gigantic. I've also tried `~~~`, ```` ```lang ```` / `~~~lang`, `~~~{lang}`, and `~~~{.lang}`. Please also note link from earlier to a similar question, where I tried to escape the special characters.

### Input

---

````
Markdown **stuff** 
```
#include <blarg>

/*!
* \brief brief description here
* \file filename.ext
*/

class ClassName{
private:
int magicnumber;
public:
void dostuff();
};
```   
Some `markdown` stuff
````

---

### Output

---

> ## Markdown **stuff**
>
> brief description here
>
> ``` #include
>
> /*! **

---

Comment: Can you provide an example to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Completed update with sample output, @albert